# How do you loop read for c++ sockets?

Tags: c++, string, sockets, loops

How do you loop read for c++ sockets.

```
stringstream ss;
while (1) {
    char buf [2];
    ssize_t e = read(fd, buf, 2);

    ss << buf[0];
    ss << buf[1];



    cout << e << endl;
    cout << buf[0] << endl;
    cout << buf[1] << endl;

    if (e <= 0) {
        break;
    }
}
string msg = "";
ss >> msg;
```

When I telnet and type hello and then enter to test this out, I get

```
2
h
e
2
l
l
2
o

1
```

And it just waits there, no looping.  What is going on, and how do I read sockets?

How do I signify EOF using

1. telnet
2. buf in the context of write(fd, buf, bufSize);

Comment: Yes, it's waiting on `read()`, which is a blocking call.

Comment: How do I get it to recognize that it's eof?

Comment: The connection will break.  `read()` will return either -1 (then check `errno`) or 0.  0 indicates the other end disconnected.

Comment: So I need to disconnect to signify eof? So if I were the client I would do write, close, read?

Comment: You have two bugs: First, you don't check if `e == 1`. Short reads are always possible with TCP. Second, you check if `e <= 0` *after* processing the data you didn't read.

Comment: Derek: Protocols that use TCP do not normally use connection shutdown to signify much of anything. One of the reasons they do this is that process termination can trigger a connection shutdown, and you don't want to confuse that with normal end of data. And, of course, you can't fully shut down a connection if you still plan to read data from it.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I'm really confused on how tcp is suppose to work client/server with write and read, is there a resource you could point me to that would explain this to me

Comment: @DavidSchwartz What do you mean by "check if e <= 0 after processing the data you didn't read." Where should my if statement be?

Comment: Your `if` should be before processing the data, for example with `ss << buf[0]`. [This](http://condor.depaul.edu/jkristof/technotes/tcp.html) may be a helpful introduction to TCP. It seems you are expecting the protocol to magically work without you having to code it. If you want to detect a complete message, you have to write code to do that by defining what constitutes a "complete message", checking for that condition, and acting on it.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean no looping? Typo some more, press enter and you'll see some more output..

If you finished, you have to press Ctrl+D to signal the end of input (EOF).

Comment: Ctrl+D isn't giving me EOF on telnet

Comment: On windows I think it is Ctrl-Z, *nix is Ctrl-D.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I signify EOF using
>
> 1) telnet
>
> 2) buf in the context of write(fd, buf, bufSize);

First, it's not EOF that you want to signal. It's "end of message" or "the data you have just received is a complete protocol data unit and you should now process it". And the answer is, *however you want*, so long as both sides agree.

For example, you could reserve the `~` character specifically to mark the end of a message. To indicate the end of a message, one side sends a `~`. The other side knows that when it receives a `~`, everything before that is a single message and everything after it is a new message.

You can also send the length of a message prior to sending the actual message. You can do it in text followed by a zero byte or by a line feed. Or you can make each message a line.

You can do it however makes the most sense in your specific application, but you actually have to do it.

There are two cases where TCP does do it for you:

1) When a side is completely done sending and knows the other side will not send anymore data anyway, it can use `close` on the socket. The other side will read the rest of the data already sent and then `read` will return `0`.

2) When a side is not going to send any more data but the other side might send more data, it can `shutdown` its side of the connection. It can never send any more data though. The other side will know about this shutdown, and if specifically coded to do so, can continue to send data until it shuts down its half. Then the other side's `read` will return zero. (Note that if you do this to a program that wasn't designed to take it, it will likely get confused and not realize it can still send data to you.)

Otherwise, it's all up to you.

Comment: Client: 1.connect, 2.write, 4.close, 6.read| Server: 3.read, 5.write, 7.close,  Can I run the code in this order with the sockfd of 2. and 6. be the same?

Comment: You can't read after you close. However, the client can shut down its write side of the socket and if the server is coded correctly, it can interpret the partial shutdown as the end of the message the client is sending. I don't recommend doing this though.

Answer (score 0):

TCP packets are a stream, not a file.  It is up to you how the stream is read.

In general, if you write 20 bytes at one end, you'll get 20 bytes at the other end in one read, barring the use of some common tcp/ip options.

There are assumptions made below.  Some of the assumptions are:

Assume all the scaffolding code is there.

Assume I made mistakes and debug it yourself.

Assume all byte order issues are handled.

Assume you're smart enough not to send floating point types as binary.

- Some programmers choose to use a length prefixed packet and read the length byte(2) and then read as many bytes as that length represents, like so.

  ```
   unsigned char buffer[MAX_CHAR] = "";
   unsigned char length = 0;
   int bytesRead = 0;

   read( fd, sizeof( length ), &length );
   // Handle failure from read
   while( bytesRead < length )
   {
       int readRv = read( fd, &buffer[bytesRead], length - bytesRead );
       if( readRv <= 0 )  // 0 usually means socket was closed. -1 is an erro
       {
           // Handle socket error/closed socket
       }
       else if( readRv < length )
       {
           bytesRead += readRv;
       }
       else if( readRv == length )
       {
           bytesRead = readRv;
           break;
       }
   }
  ```
- Some programmers read what is available and look for an end of packet marker

  ```
   unsigned char buffer[MAX_CHAR] = "";
   unsigned char length = 0;
   int bytesRead = 0;
   int readRv = read( fd, buffer, sizeof( buffer ) );
   int eopFound = 0;


   if( (eopFound = findEndOfPacketMarker( buffer )) > 0 )
   {
       // Less than 0 = error.
   }
   else if( eopFound == 0 )
   {
       // No end of packet, must read more bytes here
   }
   else
   {
       // Found an end of packet marker
   }

   // Here you deal with bytes that are "over read"
   // Either the
   // 1) packet was bigger than buffer,
   // 2) there were bytes left over after the EOP marker
   // 3) Martians crapped in your code and screwed it all up. :)
  ```
- Some programmers use a fixed sized set of packets and a packet type id

  ```
  int packetType;

   unsigned char buffer[MAX_CHAR] = "";
   unsigned char length = 0;
   int bytesRead = 0;

   read( fd, sizeof( packetType ), &packetType );
   read( fd, getLengthFromPacketType( packetType ), buffer );
  ```

That should cover most things...
If you have more questions, please ask in the comments with the `@`JimR thingy so it shows up as a message for me to read.